# How to run BeforeAll and AfterAll for multiple suites in Scalatest

Tags: scala, functional-testing, scalatest

My scenario for test is that I have following hierarchy:

```
AfterAll
  AfterAll
    Test Suite for Component 1 with multiple test cases
  BeforeAll
  AfterAll
    Test Suite for Component 2 with multiple test cases
  BeforeAll
  AfterAll
    Test Suite for Component 2 with multiple test cases
  BeforeAll
BeforeAll
```

Now I have the idea that I can run my setup part before and after a Suite and each Test Case, but **is there a way that i can run my setup before and after all Test Suites**

Comment: Are you saying you want to have separate `beforeAll` and `afterAll` for component1 and component 2??

Comment: No I want same beforeAll and afterAll for all these components, and I will be having separate beforeAll and afterAll as well, I have the idea of how to put the later one.

Comment: Ok, so you want common `beforeAll` and `afterAll` for both also with their individual `beforeAll` and `afterAll`. I guess you will write 2 Components in 2 different test files, is that right?

Comment: Yes you got it right. this is what I am looking for, as I can have different scenarios for different compnents

Answer (score 3):

You can leverage inheritance to replicate the setup across a variety of suites, it's slightly manual but it's a very common approach.

```
trait DefaultSuite extends Suite with BeforeAndAfterAll with Informing {
  override def beforeAll(): Unit = {..}
  override def afterAll(): Unit = {..}
}


class Component1Tests extends FlatSpec with DefaultSuite {}
class Component2Tests extends FlatSpec with DefaultSuite {}
class Component3Tests extends FlatSpec with DefaultSuite {}
```

If you want something that only runs once, before and after everying, you need to get a little smarter. In some cases an SBT plugin or task to deal with the most advanced scenarios, in others you do something like this:

```
object Singleton {
  val dbConnection = DB(..)
}

trait DefaultSuite extends Suite with BeforeAndAfterAll with Informing {
  def dbConnection: DB = Singleton.dbConnection
}
```

So implementors of your `DefaultSuite` will be able to access a bunch of things easily, but behind the scenes there is only a single instance of a particular object. I've used this technique quite successfully in the past, where a singleton and a trait are used to provide "fake" inheritance, but actually you are referencing the same instance of various objects.

Comment: Not sure if I get you completely, in first part, you suggested and common beforeAll and AfterAll . And in second part you showed me that tasks I want to do only once for entire suite I should use object from Scala. Is it like that?